# Best two round game organization

Tags: polynomials, inequalities

Consider some game (say, table tennis) with two players, in each play outcome is random and independent from previous outcomes. Assume also that probability of winning is fixed for first player and equals to $p$.

If $n$ is odd integer, probability that first player wins more than half of games is 
$$
f_n(p) = \sum_{k\ =\frac{n+1}2}^{n} \binom n k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$

So, which assume there are another odd integer $m$. If there are $m$ rounds with $n$ plays each, probability that first player wins is exactly $f_m(f_n(p))$.

The question is: how to compare $f_n(f_m(p))$ and $f_m(f_n(p))$? Which scheme has better "polorazing" properties? I'm particulary interested in case when $p$ is close to $\frac 1 2$, say $p = \frac 1 2 + \varepsilon$. How to compare values in this points?

I'm also interested in comparison with function $f_{nm}(p)$.

I have a feeling this is may be connected to analysis of boolean functions and Fourier transform on Boolean cube, but is didn't found appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer only to the very easy part —- namely, we show that, if $m,n>1$ are odd numbers and $p>1/2$, then $f_{mn}(p)>f_m(f_n(p))$.

In both cases, all elementary events are indexed by subsets $I\subseteq 2^{[mn]}$, their probabilities being equal to
$$
  P_I=p^{|I|}(1-p)^{mn-|I|}.
$$
Consider the multiset $S$ of all such elementary probabilities $P_I$. Both $f_{mn}(p)$ and $f_m(f_n(p))$ are sums of exactly half of elements in $S$.  But $f_{mn}(p)$ is the sum of the largest half in $S$, while  $f_m(f_n(p))$ is the sum of *some* half (it includes at least one element from the smallest half!). Hence the result.